# java fx can't image doesn't show

Tags: image, javafx

i have  a problem with displaying images in java fx.I want to simply display image which i get from string path.My image in this case images.jpg is in src folder of the project.
so far i got code like this: 
FXML FILE:

```
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com /javafx/8">
<children>
  <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CONTROLLER CLASS:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class MainPaneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

private Image image;
String path;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    String path = "indeks.jpg";
    imageView = new ImageView();
    image = new Image(path);
    imageView.setImage(image);

}

public ImageView getImageView() {
    return imageView;
}

public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

MAIN CLASS:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent parent = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(
            "/pl/gallery/view/MainPane.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you check if image = new Image("images.jpg"); returns an image - probably the path is wrong?

Comment: i think that initialize method doesn't start at all.because when i changed code to :
 @Override
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    System.out.println("Hello"); } i didnt see anything in console

Comment: You have to add `<AnchorPane  fx:controller="path.to.MainPaneController" ...` in your FXML file

Comment: yes, i just did this thanks now it works i was about editing this comment. so how exactly should i check if my path is correct? like i wrote i have "indeks.jpg" located in src folder of this project.

Comment: if(image.getClass() == Image.class) {
   System.out.println("yes");
  }  if this a correct way to check it...it prints yes in console so it's a object of the Image class

Comment: but it still doesn't display image ...

Comment: @thosenumbers Usually i put images in resource dir and then get them the same way, you got your fxml: `getClass().getResource();` but if you want to put image somewhere else or it is some user content, (like photo in some user dir) you can try to use something like this: `File f = new File(PATH_TO_IMAGE); if (f.exists()) String filename = f.toURI().toString();` where `Image img = new Image(filename)` Probably there are other ways, i just prefer this one.

Comment: varenn thank you very much it works.but i have a question why it didn't work before? so it's not enough to do sth like this:String path = "indeks.jpg";
    imageView = new ImageView();
    image = new Image(path);
    imageView.setImage(image); ? i need to write this file path everytime i need to display image?can u explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: @thosenumbers `String path = "indeks.jpg"  image = new Image(path);` is relative path and Image can't find this path for some reason. `new File(PATH).toURI().toString();` gives absolute path from relative, so after File().toURI() you will have not "indeks.jpg", but something like `file:/C:/path/to/your/file/indeks.jpg`. for more info you should probably look into src code of both `File` and `Image` classes.

Comment: @varenn thank you very much for your reply ,now it is clear for me.